# Angular 2 - Node - gulp | can not find module .component

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, gulp, gulp-typescript

I'm trying to build a full typescript app with nodejs in typescript to Angular 2 with a gulp build tool.

The gulp compiles everything from `/src` to `/dist`, from `.ts` to `.js` with (almost) no problems.

When I start the app everything works fine except:

> zone.js:101 GET `http://localhost:3000/app/boot.component` 404 (Not
>   Found).

But when I change

`import { BootComponent } from './app/boot.component';`

to

`import { BootComponent } from './app/boot.component.js';`

I only get a ts error (of course, because he will look for a .ts file), but it works.

How do I get this to work without adding the .js?

this is my sysmtemjs.config.js :

```
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    '@angular':                   'lib/@angular',
    'rxjs':                       'lib/rxjs'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'main':                       { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router'
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  for (var x in ngPackageNames) {
    packIndex(ngPackageNames[x]);
  }

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

in my index.html i also have to import main as main.js:

```
System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
```

Comment: Using SystemJS? If yes, then post your systemjs.config.js file.

Comment: @MihaiRăducanu updated post !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell SystemJS about your app directory and how to load components from it. Do this by adding the app package in your `systemjs.config.js` file.

```
var packages = {
  'main':                       { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'app':                        { defaultExtension: 'js' },
  'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = {
    'main':                       'my_app_folder',
    '@angular':                   'lib/@angular',
    'rxjs':                       'lib/rxjs'
};
```

Where `my_app_folder` is the folder where `main.js` is found.